# jquery nice form

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

`jquery.dialog()` will create a nice floating box form. If I do not want a floating box form but just a typical form on the page. what jquery function should I call?

Answer (score 5):

None, just add an html form to the page.

Comment: if do it this way, i have to manually put in css etc..    jquery dialog() come with standard nice look and feel

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of

```
$('body').append('<form><input type="text"/></form>');
```

would add a form to the end of the page. You could also make a specific element to add the form too (like a div) or use

```
$('some_element').after('<form>...</form>');
```

to add the form after a specific element.

Comment: if i do it this way, there will be no nice css layout . just typical form. i want to have nice look and feel like .dialog()

Comment: You can always steal the css of a dialog. Firebug (a Firefox plugin) comes in handy for things like this. "ui-dialog-content" and "ui-widget-content" are the classes applied to dialog content. Adding those classes to your form container should give the desired style.

<div class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content"><form>...</form></div>